# pyjade radio inputs text not showing

Tags: python, django-views, pyjade

I'm learning about pyjade and I'm having trouble with the inputs type radio. I can't render the text of the radio

my code:

```
        .radio
            label
                input.commenttype(type="radio",name="commenttype",value="CLARIFICATION_REQUEST",checked) {% trans "Petición de Clarificación" %}
```

I can't get the text of the radio button to appear... Tnak you

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're just putting text in the radiobutton. That is not gonna work. You should try putting it one level less deep, like this:

```
   .radio
        label
            input.commenttype(type="radio",name="commenttype",value="CLARIFICATION_REQUEST",checked) 
            | {% trans "Petición de Clarificación" %}
```